# How do I run an r script from within an r script from within power BI?

Tags: r, powerbi

I have script like:

```
library('RPostgreSQL')

source('credentials.R') # Defines USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME, PORT, and HOST

postgres <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), 
    user=USERNAME, 
    password=PASSWORD, 
    dbname=DBNAME, 
    port=PORT, 
    host=HOST)

results <- dbGetQuery(postgres, "SELECT * FROM table;")
```

The script runs fine from RStudio, but when I run it as a data source in Power BI, `'credentials.R'` is not found.  How do I run this?

Comment: Posted question and answer at the same time?

Comment: Have you not noticed the "answer your own question" option? I had the question, and I checked stackoverflow to no avail, so I started to ask, but when I started to say, "because... why exactly?" I realized "oh, because the working directory in the console is not the same working directory as in PBI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the working directory.  Within RStudio, the console is in the directory that contains `'credentials.R'`.  Add the following line to the beginning of your script:

`setwd('/path/to/working/directory')`